# How to restrict access to a url/sub-url based on ip?

Tags: .htaccess

I would like https://example.com/wp-json/ and everything underneath that (so /wp-json/xxx as well as /wp-json/xxx/xxx) to be accessible from 2 IP addresses only using the `htaccess` file.

So at the top of my `htaccess` file I added:

```
<RequireAll>
    Require all granted
    Require ip 111.111.111.111 22.222.222.222
</RequireAll>
```

But how do I add the condition in `htaccess` that this only applies to `https://example.com/wp-json/` and its subfolders? Something like:

```
<If url includes https://example.com/wp-json/>
    <RequireAll>
        Require all granted
        Require ip 111.111.111.111 22.222.222.222
    </RequireAll>
</If>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> <If url includes https://example.com/wp-json/>
> ```

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/wp-json/#">
```

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html